# How to move this footer up and change table in media

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox, grid

Hi I need help I am a beginner in HTML, CSS.

Basically I have this table and footer under it, I need to move footer up and remove padding-bottom and that will change last line of table that is divided on 2 lines back to 1 line.

**Here is how its now:**

[image]

When I move footer Rerum trada should be in 1 line and bottom should be removed. Even when I move it up it doesnt change the table.

**here is my html:**

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <td class="levy__sloupec">Etiam poseure</td>
              <td class="pravy__sloupec">Nulla est</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="levy__sloupec">Fusce wisi</td>
              <td class="pravy__sloupec">2305</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="levy__sloupec">Bla hola tola et</td>
              <td class="pravy__sloupec">Rerum trada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="levy__sloupec">Vie visi</td>
              <td class="pravy__sloupec">A</td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <footer class="karta__flex">
            <footer class="karta__footer">Sumarum</footer>
            <footer class="karta__footer"><span class="karta__druheslovo">137</span></footer>
          </footer>
```

**here is my css:**

```
table {
  
  justify-content: space-between;      
  
  font-size: 1.3rem; 
  margin-top: 20px;
}


 .levy__sloupec{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  display: block;
   margin-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
 
}

.pravy__sloupec{
font-weight: 700;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 25px;
padding-bottom: 5px;

}

.karta__flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1640px) {
  .karta__table {
    position: relative; */
  }
  
  .karta__flex {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 2rem;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 50px; 
    
  }
}
```

I don't know what to change in `karta__flex` so it can be moved up and the table changes so all words are in one line. Just need to move words Rerurm trada into a one line.

Comment: Could you try to reproduce the problem [here please](https://jsfiddle.net/)? Way easier to help you this way

Comment: @Julien Duris https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=9uMKv37yn9

Comment: I juss need to move footer up so all line in the table are in one line and remove  that bottom space  in  1640px

Comment: Considering the sample you provided, table lines in your screenshot are sometimes on 2 lines because your device's width is too small, or your font size is too large for the container's width. Footer isnt the problem

Comment: <footer> tag, while multiple use of it works, should be unique per page. I could not say for sure why, but I would say because of semantics and SEO rules

Comment: @Julien Duris I know that I can change font-size, but I am copying this website from somen else visually and he had it there like this.

Comment: is there any way to move it to up so the table will move little

Comment: I am not sure precisely what is it that you are asking for, but you could try to play with `bottom`, in `.karta__flex`, inside the `@media screen and (max-width: 1640px) {` bit